# How can I get the data of a server that returned the result, I want to get that result to update to another server

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, httpconnection

I have a servlet that returns results from the database, I want to get that result from another servlet

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RequestDispatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) for this

- **void forward(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)** :
  Forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file, or HTML file) on the server
- **void include(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)**
  : includes the content of a resource (servlet, JSP page, HTML file) in the response